# Is it cheaper to redraw DOM elements or retain them within memory?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, browser

After running memory profiling on a customers web application it was discovered that a lot of their DOM elements were created and then held in memory to speed up displaying them at a later date.

It was stated: "retaining DOM elements in memory is cheaper than redrawing them."

I have struggled to find any literature for or against this argument.

Comment: You mean the customer stated that?

Comment: What does this have to do with redrawing? If you hold them in memory, the only advantage you get is that you don't need to *recreate* them at a later date. They still need to be rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Very basically, regardless of what their actual use is, here... if you change on-DOM elements in JS, then after your JS thread is done, each one of those modified elements (and any of their children, if a reflow has moved other parts of the tree) is repainted.

Painting elements is costly.
Very costly, compared to running a function.
Much like videogames, the most expensive operation is drawing to the screen.

Reflowing and repainting dozens of times, one after the other is a huge hit (or several small hits which add up).
Batching dozens of changes together off-DOM and appending them to the HTML results in one batched reflow/repaint.

That's where the real "cost" is saved -- making HTML modifications off-DOM and either appending to or replacing what's already there.
Building 6 pages in-memory, when you land on the index page isn't saving much of anything, in terms of perceivable lag, *except* for the off-DOM modification and the batched paint calls, and most of that savings can be felt "just-in-time" by building the page when it's needed (off-DOM) and appending it once it's built (as long as you aren't hanging around, waiting for async data when you start building).

You should be able to see this pretty apparently in Chrome's DevTools profiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at jsperf.com you will find hundreds of real-world tests that demonstrate in-memory vs. DOM methods for HTML manipulation.

Here is one: http://jsperf.com/render-in-memory-vs-direct-dom-insertion/2

Most DOM changes require either a document reflow or a repaint of the entire page in order to recalculation the position of everything. When you do this in memory (outside the DOM) this doesn't happen. Therefore in-memory manipulation will always be faster.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking for. Also, a jsperf test result isn't necessarily relevant for production usage, and many tests are flawed anyway (the test you linked to doesn't remove the nodes from the page, for example, which makes the comparison useless).